# Simple search page with only four elements, trying to maintain layout on resize

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to build a simple search page, similar to the structure of google main search page. I am having trouble with positioning the elements in a way that is forgiving to browser zoom. While zooming in/out, the input field for the search seems to expand and contract which messes up the layout of the webpage. So my question is, does anyone know how to maintain the initial layout of the elements in the markup below while zooming in and out?

More specifically, I would like the input field to have the exact same width as the banner above it, while zooming in/out.

Try pressing Ctrl + '+' and Ctrl + '-', on google's homepage and note how everything stays positioned the exact same way while zooming in and out. That is what I am trying to accomplish with my example.

My Markup:

```
<div style="width:1000px; border:2px solid grey;">
    <div style="margin:0px auto 0px auto; width:600px;">
        <img src="http://spiritsentient.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/foobar2000_banner1.jpg" style="width:600px; height:150px;">
    </div>
    <div style="width:800px; margin:0px auto 0px 200px;">
        <br/><input type="text" size="94">
        <select>
            <option>Option1</option>
            <option>Option2</option>
            <option>Option3</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div style="width:30px; margin:0px auto 0px auto;" >
        <input type="submit" value="search">
    </div>
</div>
```

jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/QbQS7/

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is using width="1000px" for the container div, try using % instead for example width="100%". Or at least center the element.

Then you have div containing search box aligned 200px to the left, try converting it to the % or simply center is by using margin: 0px auto;

Finally declare widths for text input and select input, so they don't overlap at certain zoom sizes. It is usually good idea to declare width to elements if their parent has declared width.

see below:

```
<div style="width:100%; border:2px solid grey;">
 <div style="margin:0px auto 0px auto; width:600px;">
     <img src="http://spiritsentient.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/foobar2000_banner1.jpg" style="width:600px; height:150px;">
 </div>     
 <div style="width:800px; margin:0px auto;">
     <input type="text" style="width: 600px" size="94">
     <select style="width: 150px;">             
      <option>Option1</option>             
      <option>Option2</option>             
      <option>Option3</option>         
     </select>     
  </div>     
  <div style="width:30px; margin:0px auto 0px auto;" >
     <input type="submit" value="search">     
  </div> 
 </div> ​
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Did you test your answer? The elements are jumping around more than before. Look... http://jsfiddle.net/QbQS7/1/

Comment: If you are talking about input and select boxes jumping around simply assign width to them, that should stop them from not fitting in containing div. see http://jsfiddle.net/QbQS7/2/